# Packaging with pyinstaller when there are custom input loaders

Tags: python, import, pyinstaller, packaging

I'm trying to generate an app on my mac from a collection of python scripts. When I use pyinstaller, it can create a binary without error but it fails at runtime because of my [custom import loader](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/). This is not surprising because my import loader looks at an environment variable to get the path, finds the file, and interprets it. If I'm packaging my app and running it elsewhere, that path variable doesn't exist and the files aren't there. I guess my expectation was that pyinstaller would interpret those files, store the interpretation, and not use the custom import at all when running the final binary. Do I have to do that bypassing logic myself? How do I make these things work together?